# how to select one element between multiple elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 5 inputs and 5 buttons. I have two problems

1. First, I want only one input to appear when a button is clicked.But
   with the code I wrote, all inputs appear together
2. The second thing is that, when each button is clicked, the value
   inside the button, which is a number here, will be displayed inside
   the input.

But with the code I wrote, by clicking on each button, the number inside it does not appear in the inptut.

In fact, by clicking on the first button, the number 1 should be displayed inside input 1.
By clicking on the second button, the number 2 will be displayed inside input 2.
By clicking on the third button, the number 3 will be displayed inside the input 3. and ....

In your opinion, the problem is the way of writing JavaScript codes or html?
Can you guide me or show me an example of this?

I would be grateful if you could guide me.

```js
let myButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".myButton");
let myInputs =  document.querySelectorAll(".myInput");
let print = document.querySelectorAll(".myInput > input");
let close = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

myButtons.forEach(function (buttonSelected, id) {
  buttonSelected.addEventListener("click", function() {
    print.value = id + 1;
    console.log(id + 1);
    for(let j = 0; j < myInputs.length; j ++ ){
        myInputs[j].classList.add("active");
    }
  })
})

for (let i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.parentNode.classList.remove("active")
    })
}
```

```css
.myInput{
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    width: 10%;
    border-radius: var(--borderRadius20);
    background: rgba(221, 199, 0, 0.2);
    -webkit-margin-end: 1rem;
    margin-inline-end: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.myInput.active{
    display: flex;
}
  
.myInput > input{
    width:90%;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.myInput > .close{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}
.myButton{
  padding: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!-- //inputs -->
<div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">    
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- //buttons -->
<ul>
    <li>
      <button class="myButton">1</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="myButton">2</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="myButton">3</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="myButton">4</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="myButton">5</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your JS code. Some things to point:

- Your variable `print` is selecting ALL inputs, so it's a nodeList that needs an index. This is why I renamed it to `prints` and added an `id` index to it.
- Same for your variable `close`>>`closes`. I also rewrote that function with `forEach` in 1 line.
- You loop, for no reason, in every click of a button and you add the active class on every input. This is why all inputs are getting displayed on each click. I removed your loop.
- Try to use [Arrow Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for more compact and better readable code.

```js
let myButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".myButton");
let myInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".myInput");
let prints = document.querySelectorAll(".myInput > input");
let closes = document.querySelectorAll(".close");

myButtons.forEach((buttonSelected, id) => {
  buttonSelected.addEventListener("click", () => {
    prints[id].value = id + 1;
    myInputs[id].classList.add("active");
  })
})

closes.forEach(close => close.addEventListener('click', () => close.parentNode.classList.remove('active')));
```

```css
.myInput {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius20);
  background: rgba(221, 199, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-margin-end: 1rem;
  margin-inline-end: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.myInput.active {
  display: flex;
}

.myInput>input {
  width: 90%;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.myInput>.close {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.myButton {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">2</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">3</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">4</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">5</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

little snippet, is it what you wanted?

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".myButton").forEach(function(buttonSelected, id) {
  buttonSelected.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const nb = e.target.innerHTML;
    hideAll();
    const el = document.querySelector('.input' + nb);
    el.innerHTML = nb;
    el.classList.add('active');
  })
})


function hideAll() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.myInput').forEach(e => {
    e.classList.remove('active');
    e.innerHTML = '';
  })
}
```

```css
.myInput {
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
  width: 10%;
  border-radius: var(--borderRadius20);
  background: rgba(221, 199, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-margin-end: 1rem;
  margin-inline-end: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.myInput.active {
  display: flex;
}

.myInput>input {
  width: 90%;
  border: none;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.myInput>.close {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.myButton {
  padding: 1rem;
  background: yellow;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<!-- //inputs -->
<div>
  <div class="myInput input1">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput input2">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput input3">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput input4">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
  <div class="myInput input5">
    <input type="text" value>
    <button class="close">close</button>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- //buttons -->
<ul>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">1</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">2</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">3</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">4</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <button class="myButton">5</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```